# Magento 2 How to override vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/view/magento/setup/popupauth.phtml

Tags: magento2

How do you add **`vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/view/magento/setup/popupauth.phtml`** to a custom theme to restyle the auth popup to match my custom theme and also add new options to it.